# <UIPrerenderedIcon> in info.plist doesn't do anything

Tags: iphone, icons, info-plist

I'm trying to replace the Icon of an app I like and I did but iPhone (iPhone 4 32bg 4.0.1) keeps adding a black background and a gloss to my new icon!

I've edited 'info.plist' on user\application*app folder 
AND 
var\mobile\applications*app folder

and added  = true

Take a look on this image : http://i56.tinypic.com/8x635u.jpg

alas, no change upon respringing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I erased the file : AppIconOverlay@2x~iphone.png

That is located : System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework

It was the way that i solved my problem , i think this can be a serious problem and it can be helpfull for the users.

This is the link that my answer is based :

http://www.macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=842429

I am running iOs 5.0.1 in my iPhone 4

It took me a long time to solve this problem , almost one week , so i thing it will help a lot of people,

Best Regards,

Glauber Felix
Majoring Computer Science at Federal University of Bahia

Comment: Does it make the icon pre-rendered in the AppStore ?

Comment: Deleting something from a private framework on your development machine will hardly be a solution when you install your app on devices.

Comment: If you read the comments section on my answer above, it turns out the OP was trying to change an app icon on his jailbroken phone, it's not a development question at all!  So he erased the gloss overlay for all his icons...

Answer (score 6):

Are you on iOS5?  iOS5 introduced a new structure within info.plist for pre-rendered icons.

The relevant key for iOS5 is (note the UIPrerenderedIcon key within the PrimaryIcon dictionary):

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>ipad icon a.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Hello, I am on iOS5. I haven´t seen this pre-defined CFBundleIcons in original plist. I heve seen your code , but in this first moment it couldn´t solve my problema. I will show you my original plist file , and my modified plist file based on your help. Original plist file : http://pastebin.com/r7GcCtsG. Modified plist file based on your help : http://pastebin.com/sDzVSHnV .Since i thank you for your help. Glauber Felix.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working... maybe it's to do with when the app is installed and therefore a respiring is not taking effect?  On my apps they include both the original CFBundleIconFiles key as well as the new one.  I guess you can try a) include the original key as well, b) add all the icons to the array rather than just the @2x file...  Also, are there multiple localizations of this file?

Comment: No , it isn´t taking effect , i have tryed to restart the iphone , but it haven´t took effect...I put all icons into the array , as in the first file , but no sucess.

Comment: I am almost 7 days trying to solve this problem, i am majoring Computer Science , and i think that this problem is one of the most difficult i have tried to solve.

Comment: Some Applications , as App Store , have the Gloss , and when i add a new icon , it automatically dissapeared  , so i become some days trying to find some way to search something in App Store Application code tha could help me with this problema , but with also no sucess... I saw in your page that you do games, so i think you are more involved with iphone modifications.... I wonder if you could try to modify one icon with Gloss in your Iphone and send me the plist before , and after the modification(if it was sucessfully done).

Comment: My e-mail : glauberfelix007@hotmail.com .Or post here in this forum.I will still try a lot , i will never give up...Best Regards. Glauber Felix

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to do this with an app you are developing (and therefore you can do this in Xcode) or is this for a 3rd party app and you're doing this on a jailbroken device?  I ask because you mention 'respringing'.  The code I posted before is from an app I have in development which has the gloss turned off - as does my game Jabbit.  For the Xcode case - make the change in Xcode and then rebuild & run the app.  You can also try removing the app and rebuilding in-case it still doesn't work.  For the jailbreak case I have no idea personally.

Comment: Hello.No , I am not developing this app , i just downloaded the application from Apple Store. I can´t use Xcode because i don´t have a Macboook. I am doing this on a jailbroken device (the latest). I´ll remove the App and do the modifications again to see if solve my problem. You have made a good work with your app. Keep up a good work and thanks for your help!!!